# Querying database size in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way to query physical database size per table in SQLite?

In MySQL, there's a meta-table called `information_schema.TABLES` that lists physical table sizes in bytes. PostgreSQL has a similar meta-table called `pg_tables`. Is there anything like this in SQLite?

Comment: According to [this document](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#the_sqlite_stat1_table), you can get the average row size in bytes from the `sqlite_stat1` table (after running the `ANALYSE` command), which you could then multiply by the row count to get a decent estimate.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the database is, it's just a file. For example:

```
$ wc -c db/development.sqlite3
2338816 db/development.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

The [sqlite3_analyzer tool](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlanalyze.html) outputs lots of information about a database, among them the amount of storage used by each table.